# Writing Dates Using POI Tutorial

Tags: apache-poi

I was going through the following tutorial to write dates using poi API in an excel sheet
http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateDateCells
but when I tried to run the code the date filed shows "###" and not the actual date!!
Here is the code snippet

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle(); 
cellStyle.setDataFormat(createHelper.createDataFormat().getFormat("m/d/yy h:mm"));
 Cell cell= row.createCell(4);
 cell.setCellValue(new Date());
 cell.setCellStyle(cellStyle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel displays a cell full of "#" signs (e.g. "########") when a cell is formatted in such a way that the resulting text is too long to display all of it in the cell.  When you open the spreadsheet in Excel, widen the column long enough and it will display the formatted date.

To get the spreadsheet to be created by POI in such a way that the column will be wide enough from the start, then you need to set the column width yourself.

```
sheet.setColumnWidth(columnIndex, width)
```

Multiply your width by 256 before passing it in, because the width units used by this method are 1/256ths of a character.  Here's the Javadoc: [Sheet](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Sheet.html)